# How to apply try catch when catch error in didag workflow

Tags: workflow

Anyone knows if possible in digdag don't stop the workflow even the code reach a error, for example, if the code below fail in getData call, then normalize will not run

```
schedule:
    cron>: 0 19 * * *

+getData:
    require>: getData

+normalization:
    require>: normalize
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just sharing how i solve this.

the requiere> param `ignore_failures: true`